# Is there a way to add url as a link to visual studio project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, url

Is there a way of adding a URL to a Visual Studio Project or Solution such that when clicking on it the web page is brought up as a tabbed document within VS)?

(I wish to get a MantisBT web page up as a tab within Visual Studio and this seemed to be the best way of doing it).

If I create a link as a shortcut in the project folder, or create a link by dragging the page from IE to the folder, this file is opened as an XML file.  Open with Browser opens it externally to VS.

If I open the .url I can then CTRL+Click on the url in the link and it will open the page as a tabbed item.  Is there a way to do this in one step?

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the play button you have a few options like page inspector, maybe you can try that? Ctrl+Shift+W is the shorcut