# Add link or shortcut to web page to Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution that requires a bit of setup to build, or at least be efficient at working on this particular project.

I have often included notes.txt files in with the source code and hope developers check those out. But often I would prefer to add a shortcut to a wiki page where screenshots and so on could be included. I would love to have this checked in to source control, so after getting the source a developer could immediately click the link and now have all the instruction they need to setup their environment.

Is this possible in a clean Visual Studio install without altering the default applications used to open files? An html page would just open as source, which may be OK, but not ideal. A windows shortcut added appears to open as text also, by default.

I would like to find a solution that would work in VS 2012 and above.

Comment: Duplicate question here (unfortunately with no answer or comment): [Is there a way to add url as a link to visual studio project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032669/is-there-a-way-to-add-url-as-a-link-to-visual-studio-project).

Answer (score 1):

My workaround for this was to add a text file to the project, then paste the link information into it. If the autopreview is enabled in Solution Explorer, clicking on the **reference links.txt** file displays the list of links in the source code window. I can click on it there.

Comment: Good idea. I forgot it will display links like that.